# Add a New Item to a Table / List

Tags: sapui5

I have a fragment / view written in XML which contains a simple table with some columns and one ColumnListItem:

```xml
<m:Table id="CorrectiveActionsTable">
  <m:columns>
    <m:Column>
      <m:Text text="Lfd. Nr"/>
    </m:Column>
    <m:Column width="30%">
      <m:Text text=""/>
    </m:Column>
    <m:Column>
      <m:Text text="gefordert von"/>
    </m:Column>
    <m:Column>
      <m:Text text="Durchführungsverantwortung"/>
    </m:Column>
    <m:Column>
      <m:Text text="Planungstermin"/>
    </m:Column>
    <m:Column>
      <m:Text text="IST-Termin"/>
    </m:Column>
  </m:columns>
  <m:ColumnListItem id="ListItem_00">
    <m:Text text="1"/>
    <m:TextArea
      value="senf"
      rows="6"
      width="100%"
    />
    <m:Input placeholder="bla"/>
    <m:Input placeholder="bla2"/>
    <m:DatePicker placeholder="bla3"/>
    <m:DatePicker placeholder="bla4"/>
  </m:ColumnListItem>
</m:Table>
<m:HBox>
  <m:Button
    text="Add Button"
    visible="true"
    press="onAddButton"
    icon="sap-icon://add"
  />
</m:HBox>
```

The Button should be used to add a new ColumnListItem to the Table.
I think I should write the `onAddButton` function in the controller but I don't know where to start.

For now, my controller looks like this:

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
  "sap/m/ColumnListItem",
  "sap/m/Text",
  "sap/m/TextArea",
  "sap/m/Input",
  "sap/m/DatePicker"
], function(Controller, ColumnListItem, Text, TextArea, Input, DatePicker) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("...", {
    onAddButton: function(oEvent) {
      var columnListItemNewLine = new ColumnListItem({
        cells: [
          new Text({
            text: "1"
          }),
          new TextArea({
            value: "senf",
            rows: "6",
            width: "30%"
          }),
          new Input({
            type: "text",
            placeholder: "bla"
          }),
          new Input({
            type: "text",
            placeholder: "bla2"
          }),
          new DatePicker({
            placeholder: "bla3"
          }),
          new Datepicker({
            placeholder: "bla4"
          })
        ]
      });
      this._oTable.addItem(columnListItemNewLine);
    }
  });
});
```

And I'm pretty sure there is a better way to do this than my approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add New Item to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951092/add-new-item-to-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Resolution

1. Bind the collection of data to the aggregation of table (e.g. `<items>`).
2. Add a new entry **via the model** (instead of to the UI directly) when the user clicks on <kbd>Add</kbd>.

Thanks to the aggregation binding, UI5 will create a new `sap.m.ColumnListItem` **for you** and you did not break the MVC pattern. Here are some examples, using..:

### `v2.ODataModel`

- Call [`createEntry`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel#methods/createEntry) and later `submitChanges` to send it to backend.
- Demo: [**plnkr.co/F3t6gI8TPUZwCOnA**](https://embed.plnkr.co/F3t6gI8TPUZwCOnA?show=preview%23%2Fitems%2FLH) (Click on the <kbd>Add</kbd> button to create a new "Flight").
- Documentation: [OData V2 - Creating Entities](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2#loio4c4cd99af9b14e08bb72470cc7cabff4)

### `v4.ODataModel`

- See the documentation topic [OData V4 - Creating an Entity](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/c9723f8265f644af91c0ed941e114d46).

### `JSONModel`

```js
globalThis.onUI5Init = () => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
], async (XMLView, JSONModel) => {
  "use strict";
  const control = await XMLView.create({
    definition: document.getElementById("myxmlview").textContent,
    models: new JSONModel({
      myArray: [],
    }),
  });
  control.placeAt("content");
});

function onAddItemPress(event) {
  const model = event.getSource().getModel();
  const newArray = model.getProperty("/myArray").concat({
    id: globalThis.crypto.randomUUID(),
    text: "My New Item",
  });
  model.setProperty("/myArray", newArray, null, true);
}
```

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<script defer id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://sdk.openui5.org/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-oninit="onUI5Init"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_horizon"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-excludejquerycompat="true"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<script id="myxmlview" type="text/xml">
  <mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" height="100%" displayBlock="true">
    <Page xmlns="sap.m" title="My Items ({= ${/myArray}.length})">
      <headerContent>
        <Button text="Add" type="Emphasized" press="onAddItemPress" />
      </headerContent>
      <Table xmlns="sap.m"
        growing="true"
        items="{
          path: '/myArray',
          templateShareable: false,
          key: 'id'
        }">
        <columns>
          <Column>
            <Text text="UUID" />
          </Column>
          <Column>
            <Text text="Text" />
          </Column>
        </columns>
        <ColumnListItem>
          <Text text="{id}" />
          <Text text="{text}" />
        </ColumnListItem>
      </Table>
    </Page>
  </mvc:View>
</script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact">
</body>
```

For client-side models such as JSONModel, calling [`setProperty`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel#methods/setProperty) is sufficient. [**DO NOT** use `push`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48157104/5846045) or modify the internal model reference directly.

---

## ⚠️ Note

Do **not** modify the control aggregation manually, e.g. via `myListControl.addItem`, **after** binding the aggregation (`items`). Instead, apply the changes from the model as described above.

Comment: is there a way to add a ColumnListItem deletion as well? @Boghyon Hoffmann

Comment: @Ren Sure, the approach is the same; manipulate the **model** via public APIs instead of the UI. In case of the V2 ODataModel, get the entity path from the clicked ColumnListItem context, pass it to the `delete` method of the model. In case of a JSONModel, create a copy of the target collection, remove the entry to delete, then pass the reduced collection to `setProperty`.  Either way, the binding will then update the UI automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

> Try with this code below

```
onAddButton: function(oEvent){
        var columnListItemNewLine = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
            cells:[
                new sap.m.Text({text: "1"}),
                new sap.m.TextArea({value: "senf", rows: "6", width: 
                "30%"}),
                new sap.m.Input({type: "text", placeholder: "bla"}),
                new sap.m.Input({type: "text", placeholder: "bla2"}),
                new sap.m.DatePicker({placeholder: "bla3"}),
                new sap.m.Datepicker({placeholder: "bla4"})
                ]
        });
        this._oTable.removeAllItems();
        this._oTable.addItem(columnListItemNewLine);
    }
```