# Bind a Drop Down on every row, added Dynamically on sap.ui.table.Table

Tags: sapui5

I have created a table with a drop down control. I am adding rows dynamically in my table. I am trying to bind my table column of drop down with a JSONModel but there are some challenges in there.

```
var oTable = this.getView().byId("myTable");
this.items.push({
  item1: "",
  item2: "",
  item3: ""
});
this.oModelJson.setData(this.items);
this.oTable.setModel(this.oModelJson);
this.oTable.bindRows("/");
```

Now, my item1 is the drop down as declared in the view. After the end of above code, I am trying to bind my table drop down using following technique: my JSONModel is global and it has data. I am able to successfully bind my drop down outside of table but when I move my drop down inside the table, it is not binding.

```
var oDDL = this.byId("DropDown");
var oDDLTemplate = new sap.ui.core.Item({
  key: "{key}",
  text: "{Text}"
});
oDDL.setModel(this.oJson);
oDDL.bindAggregation("items", "/results", oDDLTemplate);
```

Here is my view, Table

```
<t:Table id="myTable"
  width="auto"
  noDataText="No Record Found"
  busyIndicatorDelay="{detailView>/lineItemTableDelay}"
  class="sapUiResponsiveMargin"
  selectionMode="MultiToggle"
  visibleRowCount="5"
>
  <t:extension>
    <l:HorizontalLayout>
      <Button icon="sap-icon://add" text="Row" press="addRow"/>
      <Button icon="sap-icon://delete" text="Row" press="fDeleteRow"/>
    </l:HorizontalLayout>
  </t:extension>
  <t:columns>
    <t:Column width="16rem">
      <Text text="Item 1"/>
      <t:template>
        <ComboBox id="DropDown"></ComboBox>
      </t:template>
    </t:Column>
  <t:Column width="8rem">
    <Text text="Item 2"/>
    <t:template>
      <ComboBox id="txt_itm2" ></ComboBox>
    </t:template>
  </t:Column>
  <t:Column width="8rem">
    <Text text="Item 3"/>
    <t:template>
      <ComboBox id="txt_itm3" ></ComboBox>
    </t:template>
  </t:Column>
</t:Table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a minimal example: https://plnkr.co/edit/8YvXxk?p=preview

In my example above, the rows are initially empty (`[]`). The binding definitions can stay in the view:

```xml
<t:Table rows="{/}">
  <t:extension>
    <OverflowToolbar>
      <ToolbarSpacer />
      <Button
        icon="sap-icon://add"
        press=".onAddPress"
      />
    </OverflowToolbar>
  </t:extension>
  <t:columns>
    <t:Column>
      <Text text="Item 1" />
      <t:template>
        <ComboBox items="{items1}">
          <core:Item
            key="{key}"
            text="{text}"
          />
        </ComboBox>
      </t:template>
    </t:Column>
    <!-- ... -->
  </t:columns>
</t:Table>
```

By this, I just need to enhance the existing model data when the user presses on the <kbd>+</kbd> button instead of calling `bindRows` or `bindAggregation` every time.

```js
onAddPress: function() {
  const model = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel(); // JSONModel
  const currentRows = model.getProperty("/");
  const newRows = currentRows.concat(this.createEntry());
  model.setProperty("/", newRows);
},
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, @BoghyonHoffmann, your sample seems to be working only with JSON model. Is it possible to use it with OData model?

Comment: @zygimantus The approach is the same; you're always adding a new object / entity **to the model** (instead of to the UI directly). In the case of ODataModel, the appropriate API is `createEntry` as mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48226884/5846045

Comment: Hi, @BoghyonHoffmann I have a model binded to dropdown and I need to fetch multiple values from that model based on selection in dropdown. How can I do that ?