# Get Selected Value from Drop-Down Inside sap.ui.table.Table

Tags: sapui5

I have created a table with a drop-down control ([sap.m.ComboBox](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ComboBox)). I am adding rows dynamically using JSONModel. Here is the logic to bind my table:
[My Table bind logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48513979/bind-a-drop-down-on-every-row-added-dynamically-on-sap-ui-table-table/48562620#48562620).

Now, I am trying to get values from the table:

```
var oTable = this.getView().byId("mytable");
var data = oTable.getModel();
var len = oTable._iBindingLength; // Get total Line Items in table
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  var _val1 = data.oData[i].item1;
  var _val2 = data.oData[i].item2;
  // my value logic here
}
```

But this is bringing all the values instead of just selected value from my drop-down control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get selected key from the ComboBox (drop-down), bind the appropriate model data to its property `selectedKey`. Once the user selects something, the selected key will be stored in the model thanks to the *two-way* data binding.

```
<m:ComboBox width="100%"
  selectedKey="{foo/selectedKey}"
  items="{
    path: 'foo/items',
    templateShareable: false
  }"
>
  <core:Item key="{key}" text="{text}"/>
</m:ComboBox>
```

I've updated my example from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48562620/5846045): https://plnkr.co/edit/8YvXxk?p=preview

[image]

The model data is automatically updated when the user selects something from the drop-down:

[image]